# Haskell Language Server in VS code shows 'could not find module' Error

Tags: haskell, visual-studio-code

I have the following imports in my file

```
import Control.Applicative (Applicative(liftA2))
import Control.Monad ( guard )
import qualified Data.Vector as V
```

and I get the error that reads `could not find module 'Data.Vector'`

The module is installed. I have vector in `dependencies` and the program builds fine. I just can't get rid of the error in VS Code.

What extra installations do I have to do to fix this?

I have tried:
`cabal install vector --lib`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried?

```
cabal install vector --lib
```

Comment: Yes, I have. I guess I should I stated that

Comment: How about ghc-pkg expose vector?

Comment: just tried that and I don't think it did anything. No error, or change..